# How to override a subroutine such as `length` in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would like to simply override the `length` subroutine to take in account ANSI escape sequences so I wrote this:

```
sub length {
    my $str = shift;
    if ($cfg{color}) {
        return length($str =~ s/\x1B\[\d+[^m]*m//gr);
    } 
    return length($str);
}
```

Unfortunately Perl detect the ambiguous call that is remplaced with  `CORE::length`.

How can I just tell Perl to use the local declaration instead?

Of course, an alternative solution would be to rename each call to `length` with `ansi_length` and rename the custom function accordingly.

To those who want more details:

The context where I would like to override the core module `length` is a short code that generate ASCII tables (a bit like `Text::ASCIITable`, but with different features like multicolumns and multirows). I don't want to write a dedicated Perl module because I would like to keep my program as monolithic as possible because the people what will use it are not familiar with CPAN or even modules installation.

In this code, I need to know the width of each columns in each rows in order to align them properly. When a cell contain a colored text with an ANSI sequence like `^[[33mgreen^[[0m`, I need to ignore the coloring sequences.

As I already use UTF-8 chars in my Program, I had to add this to my Program:

```
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

I noticed the `utf8` module also overload the core subroutine `length`. I realized this will also be a good solution in my case.

Eventually I think I added enough details to this question. I would be glad to be notified why I got downvotes on this question. I don't think I can make this more clear. Also I think all these details are not usefull at all to understand the initial question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overwriting a core function is not a good idea. If you use a library, that itself uses the core function, the library function would be confronted with the overwritten function and may fail. You could create an own module/namespace ANSI:: or so, then use ANSI::length, but I think it is better to use a name like you proposed: ansi_length.

If you still insist:
You can overwrite the core function with

```
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::length = sub ... 
}
```

Whenever you need access to the origin CORE function, use
CORE::length.

This is valid for all built in functions of Perl.

Here is a reference : http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html

Comment: The `utf8` module overload the `length` subroutine. I understand that `utf8` is also a core module but I don't really understand in what this is different.

Comment: "utf8" is something special. A so called "pragma" or better a "feature". You can write "use utf8;"at the beginning of a script to tell perl that the text uses utf-8 encoding.

Comment: The overloading that utf8 induces is only visible in the script where you use the pragma. It's the same as "use strict." Its scope is the script where it is written in.

Comment: Re "The utf8 module overload the length subroutine", No, it doesn't. `length` always returns the number of characters (elements) in the string.